# Can't Understand the Code Order When MIPS is translated to C

Tags: c, mips, translate

I'm trying to convert MIPS code into C. I got the answer of question, but the answer I guessed is slightly different from the answers. So I want to ask you. Here is the question and the suggested answer:

Question:

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2 

add $t0, $s6, $t0 

sll $t1, $s1, 2 

add $t1, $s7, $t1 

lw $s0, 0($t0) 

addi $t2, $t0, 4 

lw $t0, 0($t2) 

add $t0, $t0, $s0 

sw $t0, 0($t1)
```

Answer:

```
B[g] = A[f + 1] + A[f];
f = A[f];
```

I thought the answer is just the reverse, because f = A[f] is firstly computed from top to bottom order. So this is my answer:

```
 f = A[f];
 B[g] = A[f + 1] + A[f];
```

I know the right answer is in the question but why? I just stuck there.

Thanks from now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, but your interpretation is not:

```
;These 2 compute the address of A[f], using pointer arithmetic
; s0 is f and s6 is A
sll  $t0, $s0, 2     ; t0 = s0 << 2
add  $t0, $s6, $t0   ; t0 = s6 + t0  -- t0 is now the address of A[f]

;These 2 compute the address of B[g], using pointer arithmetic
; s1 is g and s7 is B
sll  $t1, $s1, 2     ; t1 = s1 << 2
add  $t1, $s7, $t1   ; t1 = s7 + t1  -- t1 is now the address of B[g]

; load A[f] into s0. s0 used to be f so we can read this as f = A[f]
lw   $s0, 0($t0)     ; s0 = A[f]

; Compute address of A[f+1]
addi $t2, $t0, 4     ; t2 = t0 + 4 -- t2 is now the address of A[f+1]

; Load A[f+1]
lw   $t0, 0($t2)     ; t0 = Mem[t2] -- which is t0 = A[f+1]

; Add A[f] + A[f+1]
add  $t0, $t0, $s0   ; t0 = t0 + ts -- which is A[f] + A[f+1]
; Store  A[f] + A[f+1] into B[g]
sw  $t0, 0($t1)      ; Mem[t1] = t0 -- which is B[g] = A[f] + A[f+1]
```

If you want to express the same in a high level language, then that is indeed:

```
B[g] = A[f + 1] + A[f];
f = A[f];
```

Yours have the incorrect sequential execution result, use simple substitution to check what these mean when executed ***sequentially***:

```
f = A[f];
B[g] = A[f + 1] + A[f];
```

is the same as

```
B[g] = A[A[f] + 1] + A[A[f]];
f = A[f];
```

Which is not what the code does.

Comment: I can see what I achieved is wrong with your example. But still, I had confusion. I mean, the code firstly do the operation f = A[f] then B[g] = A[f + 1] + A[f]; isnt it ? I mean, doesn't the firstly written code must be at top ?

Comment: No, the compiler can do anything so long as your code have the same sequential semantics as the generated code. If you run the machine code, and the correct answer, they produce the same result, but if you run yours, it produces a different result (B[g]) will have a different value.